# Integrate login without browser prompt

Tags: iis, authentication, windows-authentication

I'm not sure if I should ask this question here or in ServerFault.

I'm developing a site where administrators can add users. The users can have a username and a password or can have an AD's username (from the same domain where the server is).

In the login I want to achieve that if the client is using an AD's account associated with some user, automatically login. But if it isn't using an AD's account or its using some account which is not associated with some user, I want to show the login page.

I've tried lots of different configurations but either the browser doesn't send the user account data, or (when not valid) prompts the login information.

I've also thought that maybe it could be done having two different sites for the login, but I haven't came up with any idea.

Has anyone done something similar? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you added the site to the Intranet zone in IE? Have you enabled Windows Authentication in IIS?

Comment: I'd enabled Windows Authentication, what I didn't try is IEs Intranet zone because I need it to work with both Chrome and IE.

Comment: Chrome uses the IE settings for zones.

Comment: I've just tried that, it still prompts for the login when there is no AD account. I've also tried with trusted sites with the same results :(